# How to create a sliding navigation with either jquery or css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I want to create a menu that when hovered has a sliding similar to [This website](http://www.fablelegends.com/news). Anyone have any ideas on how I would go about accomplishing this?

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Menu 1
            <ul>
                <li>Sub 1</li>
                <li>Sub 2</li>
                <li>Sub 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Menu 2</li>
        <li>Menu 3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Slide Down Menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243154/jquery-slide-down-menu)

Comment: Possible...not sure about that. The entire content slides down rather than it expanding.

Comment: I couldn't view that example site (blocked at work). But I hope [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dmCBY/) is what you are looking for. If yes, it can be done with just CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AHmLh)

HTML

```
<nav class="nav ">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="">Menu 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Sub 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Sub 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Menu 2</a>
      <ul>
                <li><a href="">Sub 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub 3</a></li>
            </ul>
      </li>
        <li><a href="">Menu 3</a>
      <ul>
                <li><a href="">Sub 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub 3</a></li>
            </ul></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
  content: " ";
  display: block
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}
.nav> ul > li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.nav > ul > li > a {
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 80px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
.nav ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: -300px;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: top 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: top 0.6s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: top 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transition: top 0.6s ease-in-out;
  background: #ddd;

}
.nav li:hover ul {
  top: 29px;
}
```